# Probability space and expected running time: what are they?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've come across an issue where I'm to calculate or state the expected running time of an algorithm, and to state the probability space of such a running time. I will be frank and say I really have no idea what I'm supposed to do. What's the difference between expected running time and average running time, and what is a probability space and why is this needed?

Comment: You're expected to calculate how much time and space an algorithm will require as the length of input increases. There is a set of notation that computer scientists use for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Further, the expected time complexity has a probabilistic interpretation.  *Given an input distribution `X`*, you can in theory formulate a random variable `Y | X` of the time complexity given a particular input.  The desired formula is the expectation of this: `E[Y | X]`.  The "probability space" is a description of the `Y | X` distribution, rather than just its expectation.  If it happened to be Gaussian, for example, specifying the mean & variance would be enough.

Answer (score 4):

They are asking you to model the **running time** of an algorithm as a **random variable** defined over a **sample space** consisting of the set of inputs of that algorithm, and to compute the **expectation** of that random variable with respect to some **probability** defined over the sample space, as the **average** of its values with respect to that probability.

Here's an example. Consider Quicksort. Quicksort is a sorting algorithm, and so it makes sense to model its set of inputs as the set of permutations of size N. So, the sample space is the set of permutations of size N. Endow that sample space with the uniform probability, and then define the running time T_N as the random variable which maps elements s of the sample space to the corresponding running time of the algorithm on input s. Then, the expectation of T_N is the average of its value over the elements of the sample space, i.e., over the set of permutations of size N. As maybe you know, E[T_N] is O(N*log(N)) (E[X] is the expectation of random variable X).

The only caveat in the previous paragraph is that you have to define mathematically what you mean by "running time". In practice, you have to take some basic operations made by the algorithm, like the number of swaps in a sorting algorithm, or the number of comparisons, and study them as the **precisely-defined** random variables that they are. After that, if you want a predictive model for your computing environment, you need to measure the time taken by your system to execute each such basic operations, and compute the expected running time as a weighted sum of the average number of basic operations times the execution time of that operation in your system, for every operation you include in your model (an example follows).

In the case of Quicksort, the number of comparisons C_N has been studied in detail, and its expectation E[C_N] is approximately 2*N*ln(N)-0.846*N. The same is true for the number of swaps S_N, whose expectation is about 0.333*N*ln(N)-1.346*N. These results are proven in chapter 1 of the book cited at the end of this post.

If you measure the running time of a comparison to be T_c, and that of a swap to be T_s in your system, your prediction of running time will be E[T_N] = T_c * E[C_N] + T_s * E[S_N]. You can then replace the previous expressions for E[C_N] and E[S_N] in order to have a precise predictive formula.

Maybe you can profit from reviewing the basics of discrete probability theory, and/or looking at an algorithm analysis textbook like Sedgewick's and Flajolet "Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms".

Comment: Great informative post, naitoon. Just one thing: I think you mean "reviewing the basics of discrete probability theory". If one were to revise the basics of discrete probability theory, they would probably win all kinds of awards :)

Comment: Hahaha :) @SauceMaster, you're right, it was completely unintended. I already edited it. Thanks, and +1 for your comment.

Comment: @naitoon - You put it very succintly to illustrate the answer. Thanks. One questions - For your example of input size N, sample space being permutations of N, how is the expectation of run time T_N as 2*N*log(N) . I know quicksort run time complexity is NLogN. But could not get the answer you gave. For a uniform distribution as u mentioned wouldn't it be Log(N) (i.e. N*Log(N) divided by N )

Comment: @goldenmean, you're right, I should have said that the expectation of T_N is O(N*log(N)), not 2*N*lg(N) (the base of the log was wrong too, BTW). I will edit my post right away. Now, WRT your second question, no, you don't divide by N since O(N*log(N)) is an already averaged result over the N! possible inputs. You can see the recurrence for the number of comparisons in http://goo.gl/xMUpK if you want. You can also watch Sedgewick's lectures on Analytic Combinatorics at coursera.org. In the first chapter you have a precise average-case analysis of Quicksort.